# Converting Generic Type into reference type after checking its type using GetType(). How?

Tags: c#, generics, type-conversion, casting

i am trying to call a function that is defined in a class `RFIDeas_Wrapper`(dll being used).
But when i checked for type of reader and after that i used it to call function it shows me error `Cannot convert type T to RFIDeas_Wrapper.`

**EDIT**

```
private List<string> GetTagCollection<T>(T Reader)
            {
                TagCollection = new List<string>();
                if (Reader.GetType() == typeof(RFIDeas_Wrapper))
                {

                    ((RFIDeas_Wrapper)Reader).OpenDevice(); 
                    // here Reader  is of type RFIDeas_Wrapper
                    //, but i m not able to convert Reader into its datatype.

                    string Tag_Id =  ((RFIDeas_Wrapper)Reader).TagID();
                    //Adds Valid Tag Ids into the collection
                    if(Tag_Id!="0")
                        TagCollection.Add(Tag_Id);
                }
                else if (Reader.GetType() == typeof(AlienReader))
                    TagCollection = ((AlienReader)Reader).TagCollection;

                return TagCollection;
            }
```

> ((RFIDeas_Wrapper)Reader).OpenDevice();
>
> ((AlienReader)Reader).TagCollection;

I want this line to be executed without any issue. As Reader will always be of the type i m specifying.
How to make compiler understand the same thing.

Comment: Why are you using `T` (which could be anything) if you need `RFIDeas_Wrapper`?

Comment: @Bobby: I could get any kind of reader. i.e AlienReader in else if part and so on. I have to make this function to work for all readers that return me List Collection. I think it should be a better approach to directly pass the class object and get the result without writing same code again and again to get some output.

Comment: I can't see the point of using generics here, because you don't get any compile-time type safety. It could be object as well.

Comment: @Stefan: If you have already read my edit, then why it is not type safe, I have checking its datatype before performing some action. It will not enter into if or else part until it doen't matches appropriate datatype.

Comment: Bobby is right, generics are not meant for this kind of code, it's a bad design.

Comment: You can put there object Reader and remove the generics and nothing changes.

Comment: @Frantisel, Bobby: What should i use in this case so as to avoid type conversion.

Comment: It depends. Change the implemetation of Readers, if you can. If you can't, what is the source of your Readers? Can't you have two overloads of GetTagCollection and call it when you create the instances of readers? Or you can create wrappers for each type of reader that would implement the method. It all depends on the conditions you have.

Comment: @Frantisek: Thanks once again, I didn't thought of overloading at the moment when i was implementing. I can see in my code that overload will be a much better solution.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

One trick is to use `object` in the middle to force it:

```
if (Reader is RFIDeas_Wrapper)
{
    ((RFIDeas_Wrapper)(object)Reader).OpenDevice(); 
    ...
}
```

or use `as`:

```
RFIDeas_Wrapper wrapper = Reader as RFIDeas_Wrapper;
if (wrapper != null)
{
    wrapper.OpenDevice();
    ...
}
```

Comment: @Marc: Then Will it be converting Reader into object type. Will I have any benefit of using T type. I was trying to avoid type conversion. Is it something the same thing or will it be converting it into object type first then its appropriate class type. ?

Comment: @Shantanu Gupta : We aren't converting the object; we are simply casting the reference. As others have noted, it would work the same without the generics. The problem, though, is that by doing this you probably introduce boxing *anyway* (if you have value-type T)

Comment: @Marc: When should i use T type in these type of cases. When I may get value type as well as reference type ?

Comment: @Shantanu - I'd use `T` when it *adds* something. It doesn't really add anything in your case; just use `object`.

Comment: @Marc: adds something means, I didn't get you exactly. I m now using object rather than T, but still would like to know reason.

Comment: @Shantanu: T is usually good when using with lists - you want to insert objects of T and return objects of T but you don't care about what T actually is (so you don't need to call methods of the objects): List<T> allow you to add objects of T and return object of T allowing you to use List<int>.Add(int), but the list itself does not use the methods of T because it does not need to care.

Comment: @Frantisek: I understood 100% of what you was trying to deliver. I appreciate for your effort. I was using T till now for making my code reusable rather than what you explained. As We are not using Generic types, Collections at all so I wanted to use them but never knew the purpose. Thanks anyway I would now try to use them in actual direction where they should be used.